# How to redirect my site with .htaccess

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

I need redirect `http://site.com/language/arg1/arg2` to `http://site.com/language/mainpage/explore/arg1/arg2`

I don't have big experience with .htaccess, so I have a problem.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mainpage$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/???/mainpage/explore/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**First problem**: the result is many redirects (310 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS). I guess, error in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mainpage$` ?

**Second problem**: section "language" may take several variants ("ru", "en", etc.). What I must to write instead of "???" in the fourth line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by CI routing in `routes.php` also like

```
$route['language/(:any)/(:any)']    = "language/mainpage/explore/$1/$2";
```

In .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^language/([^//]+)/([^//]+)$ language/mainpage/explore/$1/$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I have modified routes.php already, and I don't want to touch it. But thank you for your answer

Comment: My apologize, I was wrong. Solution with routes.php is better. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but this should be what you're searching for :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mainpage/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/(.*)$ http://site.com/$1/mainpage/explore/$2 [R=301,L]
```

- Change your second `{HTTP_HOST}` into `{REQUEST_URI}` (`mainpage` isn't in your hostname)
- Remove the `$` from your second condition (`mainpage` isn't at the end of your uri)
- Use two catching groups, one for the language, the second for arguments
- Restrict the language : only allow one or more letters with `([A-Za-z]+)`

Note : your code will only work for `site.com`, not `www.site.com`

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need, but I have one more question. I have section in .htaccess

`RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]`

I need combine them or modify your RewriteRule line?

Comment: @indapublic You should be alright - the 'mainpage/explore' rule will force the browser to reload the page, so your condition looking for a valid filename is still processed on the second page load.  Also, RewriteCond directives only apply to the first RewriteRule that follows them; so you can have multiple RewriteCond/RewriteRule pairings without any extra syntax to separate them.